# trigger scenario, anybody help plz

Tags: apex, trigger

have to update the "total actual cost field" in custom object called "project portfolio" from its associated custom object called "projects"'s fiels total actual cost. means all the "total actual cost" fields of different projects associated with the "project portfolio" should come into "total actual cost" field of "project portfolio"

Both have total actual cost field.

code-

```
trigger UpdateTotalActualCost on CloudbyzITPM__Project_Portfolio__c (after insert, after update) 
{

          List<CloudbyzITPM__Project_Portfolio__c> Portfoliorecords =
         (List<CloudbyzITPM__Project_Portfolio__c>)Trigger.New;
     Set<id> recordId = new Set<id>();
     for(CloudbyzITPM__Project_Portfolio__c  port : Portfoliorecords)
     {
     recordId.add(port.id);
     }

     List<CloudbyzITPM__Project__c> fn = [Select id,
CloudbyzITPM__Total_Costs__c from CloudbyzITPM__Project__c where id IN
:recordId];
     if(fn.size()>0)
     {
     for(CloudbyzITPM__Project__c  affc : fn)
     {
     Portfoliorecords.CloudbyzITPM__Total_Actual_Cost__c =
Portfoliorecords.CloudbyzITPM__Total_Actual_Cost__c +
affc.CloudbyzITPM__Total_Costs__c;
     }
     }
    update Portfoliorecords ;
}
```

error - "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List"

Comment: use rollup summary field instead of code if possible

Comment: can't use rollup summary field, there is a look up relationship between objects.

Comment: Hi Shravan,     Can u help me with the code. or exactly why iam getting this error.

Comment: looking into this give 10mins

Comment: your getting error because directly assigning value into list. that is not possible without iteration of list.

Comment: You can still do rollup through lookup, take a look at the dlrs tool.

Answer (score 0):

Deepak, I have tried using parent and child object in this following code. please change according to your code.

```
trigger UpdateTotalActualCost on childobject (after insert, after update) {

List<Id> parentIdList = new List<Id>();
Map<Id,integer> totalMap = new Map<Id,Integer>(); 

for(childObject child : Trigger.new) {
    parentIdList.add(child.parentField);
        integer temp = 0;
    if(totalMap.containsKey(child.parentField)) {
            temp = totalMap.get(child.parentField);     
    }
    totalMap.put(child.parentField,child.amount + temp)

}

List<ParentObject> parentList = [select id,total from parentObject where id in :parentIdlist];

for(parentobject parent: parentList) {
if(totalMap.containsKey(id)) {
    parent.total = totalMap.get(id);
}
update parentList;

}
```

Comment: Hi Shravan,               what is that amount field on line 10. I have ..Api names like.     Project- CloudbyzITPM__Project__c.        Project Portfolio- CloudbyzITPM__Project_Portfolio__c.        Field name- CloudbyzITPM__Total_Actual_Cost__c.

Comment: your child aggregated field

Comment: I have ..Api names like. Project- CloudbyzITPM__Project__c. Project Portfolio- CloudbyzITPM__Project_Portfolio__c. Field name- CloudbyzITPM__Total_Actual_Cost__c.  I don't have this child aggregate field